# Need to pass Viewbag and TemplateInfo to partial view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So the question of how to pass Viewbag data to a partial view has been answered on here multiple times, but I need to pass the viewbag info and the TemplateInfo to my partial view and I can't find a single question that deals with that.  Part of my controller looks like this.

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("AboutActivity", (Transport.Models.Tracking.TravelRequest.AboutActivityModel)Model,
              new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AboutActivity" } });}
</div>
```

This works fine in mapping my objects back to the model and all, but I have a few views that need to load dropdowns from the ViewBag data as so.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Destination.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.States)
```

How can I pass both the ViewBag data and the TemplateInfo prefix to.

Comment: you can add the States list to your AboutActivityModel as a property and it will always follow it around

Comment: I would prefer not to messy up the model with that data if I don't need to, but if I can't pass both, then that is what I will have to do.

Comment: You would be far better doing this as an `EditorTemplate` rather than a partial hack (i.e. by renaming your `AboutActivity` partial to `AboutActivityModel.cshtml` and putting it in the `EditorTemplates` folder and using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AboutActivity, new { states = ViewBag.States})` in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly pass the ViewBag data from your main view to your partial view. As long as you have it available in your main view( *that means you set the ViewBag data in your GET action*), It will be available in the partial view as well.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var states = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "MI", Text = "MI"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "OH", Text = "MOH"}           
   };
   ViewBag.States = states;
   return view();
}
```

And in your Index and the partial view which is being invoked from the Index view, ViewBag.States is accessible.

**Index view**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Destination.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.States)
<div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("AboutActivity"); }
</div>
```

**Partial view *(AboutActivity*)**

```
<h2>My PartialView</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("Destination.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.States)
```

A better solution is to **not use dynamic stuff like ViewBag and ViewData** to pass data between action methods and views. Why not add a new property to your view model of type `List<SelectListItem>` for the dropdown data and use that ?

```
public class AboutActivityViewModel
{
  public List<SelectListItem> States {set;get;}
  public int SelectedState {set;get;}    
  // Other properties for the view as needed
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
   var vm = new AboutActivityViewModel();
   vm.States = new List<SelectListItem>
   {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "MI", Text = "MI"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "OH", Text = "MOH"}           
   };      
   return view(vm);
}
```

And your view which is strongly typed to AboutActivityViewModel

```
@model AboutActivityViewModel
<div>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("AboutActivity"); }
</div>
```

And in your Partial view, which is also strongly typed.

```
@model AboutActivityViewModel     
@Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedState, Model.States)
```

*If you do not pass a model to the partial view explicitly, It will use the model of the parent page from it is called.*

In your case, you are passing a totally new `ViewDataDictionary` to the partial which will overwrite the States you set to the ViewBag earlier. So you should make sure that you are reading the States from existing ViewBag  and set that to the new `ViewDataDictionary` you are passing.

```
<div>

    @{ Html.RenderPartial("AboutActivity", Model, new ViewDataDictionary
        {
            TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AboutActivity" },
            ["States"] = ViewBag.States
        });
     }
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the viewbag is shared between them.  When I look at the viewbag in my partial for states it is null, but when I am in Index view, it has 53 records in it.

Comment: Yes. because you are overwriting it. See my updated answer.

Comment: When I implement you updated solution, I get a compilation Error.  It doesn't like the '['.

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term '['

      @{Html.RenderPartial("AboutLodging", (Transport.Models.Tracking.TravelRequest.AboutLodgingModel)Model,                new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "AboutLodging" }, ["States"] = ViewBag.States });}

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from your comment and it worked fine for me. I guess some other code is giving you trouble.